# subtract dataframes with different dimentions

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dataframe, slice

Is there a way to subtract dataframes with different dimensions?
I have A with [300X1] and B with [300X188] dataframes. I want to subtract the A column to all the B column values.
I tried a while loop to take B matrix 1 column at a time to subtract but got an error says TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'.

something like this...

```
A  B
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  2 2 3 4 5 
9  3 2 3 4 5   
6  4 2 3 4 5 
8  5 2 3 4 5
```

output:

```
New Table
7 6 5 4 3
7 7 6 5 4
6 7 6 5 4
2 4 3 2 1
3 6 5 4 3
```

Comment: Please post the code which gives you the error you are mentioning.

Comment: Try `A[:, np.newaxis] - B`. This works for me with `A = np.arange(5)` and `B = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)` (shape of `A` is then `(5, )`, not `(5, 1)`).

Comment: @Michael I tried and I got an error saying TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'. I think in python 3 A returns in string form instead to integer.
I tried to convert A to integers by doing `int(A)` and get another error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Those are errors that don't occur in my example with `np.arange` which is an array with dtype `int`. By the way, I use Python 3.4, so it's not an error of Python 3. Show us a minimal working example that produces your error.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your dataframes to numpy arrays

```
new_table = pd.DataFrame(A.values - B.values)

print(new_table)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  7  6  5  4  3
1  7  7  6  5  4
2  6  7  6  5  4
3  2  4  3  2  1
4  3  6  5  4  3
```